# Is it possible to enable native video calling in stock android?

Tags: stock-android, 9.0-pie, video-calling

My phone's IMS status shows that video calling is unavailable that I can't do native video calling.

I'm using stock android on Asus  Zenfone Max Pro M2.
Android version 9.0.

So is it possible to activate video calling.

Comment: From what I can tell, IMS requires the carrier to support the software & hardware. But that's not say you couldn't do video calling over a separate service/app.

Comment: Yes I can't do native video calling.